# How import library?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I want to create XML with this code :

```
public static void CreateXML (){
    try{
        XMLOutputter xmlOut = new XMLOutputter();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I have this error :

```
XMLParcourt.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
XMLOutputter xmlOut = new XMLOutputter();
                          ^
symbol:   class XMLOutputter
location: class XMLParcourt
```

Maybe it because Jdom library is not import, but how import library with vs code?...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score -1):

try to add lib with XMLOutputter class into the class path.